# Encrypting and Decrypting Url & HTML

Tags: encryption, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any open source hacker safe encryption & decryption algorithm for encrypting & decrypting URL Query String values & HTML for ASP.NET MVC4?

I googled many, but every source has some DLL reference to it for which i cant find any source.

Comment: please define "hacker safe" ... what are the attack scenarios you want to protect against?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, Sorry I dont know the methods involved behind hacking with url parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some of the existing [`symmetric encryption algorithms`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) that are built in .NET. For example the [`AES algorithm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx) is an industry standard that you could use.

But my advice would be the following: if you want to be safe, then simply do not send this information to the client (as part of the query string in your case) but keep it on the server.